# wpf string format integer 1234 to 12:34 only in XAML

Tags: wpf, string-formatting

I have 1234 value and I have to show it as 0012:34 and when user clicks on that text box to edit the value, it should display only 1234  and when tabs out it should go back to 0012:34. If I use a converter, it does not change the format when got focus. I have this text box inside a data template and cannot access it in code behind also, meaning, I cannot do the formatting in Got_Focus event. Can anyone help with the formatting please?
I can use int or string as the datatype.

Thanks,
Rosy

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WatermarkTextBox](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WatermarkTextBox&referringTitle=Home) from [Extended WPF Toolkit](http://nuget.org/packages/Extended.Wpf.Toolkit):

```
<xctk:WatermarkTextBox Text="{Binding Value}" Watermark="{Binding Value, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource YourValueConverter}}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to a watermark textbox you could use a behavior.

`System.Windows.Interactivity` needs to be referenced.

Example:

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WatermarkTextBox.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        xmlns:WatermarkTextBox="clr-namespace:WatermarkTextBox" Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Width="300" Height="30">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <WatermarkTextBox:WatermarkBehavior />
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </TextBox>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Width="300" Height="30" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Behavior:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;

namespace WatermarkTextBox
{
    public class WatermarkBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
    {
        private string _value = string.Empty;

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            AssociatedObject.GotFocus += OnGotFocus;
            AssociatedObject.LostFocus += OnLostFocus;
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            AssociatedObject.GotFocus -= OnGotFocus;
            AssociatedObject.LostFocus -= OnLostFocus;
        }

        private void OnGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AssociatedObject.Text = _value;
        }

        private void OnLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _value = AssociatedObject.Text;
            AssociatedObject.Text = string.Format("Watermark format for: {0}", _value);
        }
    }
}
```